# Create variable from $_POST array in php

Tags: php, arrays, post

I am having a `$_POST` array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [veryfy_doc_type] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )

    [id_number] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3242424
                [1] => 4456889
            )

    [document_issuer] => Array
            (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
            )

    [verify_doc_expiry_date] => Array
            (
                    [0] => 2016-01-26
                    [1] => 2015-02-20
            )

    [doc_id] => Array
            (
                    [0] => 15
                    [1] => 16
            )

    [user_id] => Array
            (
                    [0] => 14
                    [1] => 14
            )
)
```

Using this array I need to get each values into php variables.

I tried it something like this, but it doesn't work for me.

```
foreach($_POST AS $k => $v) { 
    //print_r($v); 
    list($doc_type, $id_number, $issuer, $expiry_date, $doc_id, $user_id) = $v;
}

echo "Type = $doc_type";
```

Can anybody tell me how to figure this out. 
Thank you.

Comment: $_POST _is_  php variable, so the values already are "in" one ;-)

Comment: $doc_type will be 1 or 2? it cant be both

Comment: @Dagon, $doc_type values can not be same.

Comment: @Terminus, I checked the question that you have linked. but not sure how it help for this scenario. Can you kindly show me an example. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried to use extract?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you since you can also use `extract` in php to create variables.

```
<?php
$_POST = array(
    'veryfy_doc_type'=> array(1,2),
    'id_number' => array(3242424,4456889),
    'document_issuer'=> array(1,3),
    'verify_doc_expiry_date'=> array('2016-01-26','2015-02-20'),
    'doc_id' => array(15,16),
    'doc_id' => array(14,14)
);


extract($_POST);
print_r($veryfy_doc_type);
print_r($id_number);
```

Comment: Dangerous thing to suggest when you're dealing with posted data.

Comment: A lot of things are dangerous. It's up to the developer to make that call.

Comment: @Robbiee I dont know how could it be dangerous if he will just use a certain index that you know.I think you are also saying that using $_POST['post_name'] variable is dangerous.. when in fact you know the post_name index.

Comment: I mean that if you use say $userId in your script then someone could post that variable and have it potentially overwrite yours. Use with caution is all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to reference each of the sub-array values while looping the main array... maybe something like this?

```
// Loop one of the sub arrays - you need to know how many times to loop!
foreach ($_POST['veryfy_doc_type'] as $key => $value) {
    // Filter the main array and use the $key (0 or 1) for the callback
    $rowValues = array_map(function($row) use ($key) {
        // Return the sub-array value using the $key (0 or 1) for this level
        return $row[$key];
    }, $_POST);

    print_r($rowValues);
}
```

Example: https://eval.in/498895

This would get you structured arrays for each set of data.

From here I'd suggest you leave the arrays as they are rather than exporting to variables, but if you wanted to you you could use the `list()` as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) for that:

```
<?php
$post = array(
    'veryfy_doc_type' => array('1','2'),
    'id_number' => array('3242424','4456889'),
    'document_issuer' => array(1,3),
    'verify_doc_expiry_date' => array('2016-01-26','2015-02-20'),
    'doc_id' => array(15,16),
    'user_id' => array(14,14)
);


$mit = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC);
foreach($post as $k=>$v) {
    $mit->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator($v), $k);
}


foreach( $mit as $row ) {
    echo $row['doc_id'], ' ', $row['id_number'], ' ', $row['verify_doc_expiry_date'], "\r\n";
}
```

prints

```
15 3242424 2016-01-26
16 4456889 2015-02-20
```

If you have control over the client code you can change the names of the POST parameters in a way that php build this structure automagically. E.g.

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="record[0][veryfy_doc_type]" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[0][id_number]" value="3242424" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[0][document_issuer]" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[0][verify_doc_expiry_date]" value="2016-01-26" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[0][doc_id]" value="15" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[0][user_id]" value="14" />

    <input type="hidden" name="record[1][veryfy_doc_type]" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[1][id_number]" value="4456889" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[1][document_issuer]" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[1][verify_doc_expiry_date]" value="2015-02-20" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[1][doc_id]" value="16" />
    <input type="hidden" name="record[1][user_id]" value="14" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

would do/cause that.

Comment: Can you show me how to use `list()` within foreach loop. I tried it something like this `list($doc_type, $id_number, $issuer, $expiry_date, $doc_id, $user_id) = $row;`. But it have `Undefined offset: 5` error.

Comment: Change `MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_ASSOC` to `MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC`. But why not simply use $row? There's no need for additional pollution of the variable namespace.

Comment: I need execute an update query. something like this : `$stmt->bind_param('iissii', $doc_type,$id_number, $issuer, $expiry_date, $doc_id, $user_id);
foreach ($mit as $row) {
  list($doc_type, $id_number, $issuer, $expiry_date, $doc_id, $user_id) = $row;
  $stmt->execute();
}`

Comment: Is there other way to do it without using `list()`;

Comment: In that special case I'd go with list() as well.

Comment: Ok.. Thank you, one question can you explain this `If you have control over the client code you can change the names of the POST parameters in a way that php build this structure automagically. ` in you answer.

Comment: Just try the form code. Post it to a script like `<pre><?php var_export($_POST); ?></pre>` and you will see what I mean. You would then iterate the data with something like `foreach( $_POST['record'] as $row ) { ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the value of the post then you can have a simple multidimentional loop. no need to make it broad

```
   foreach($_POST as $keyName => $row){
      // $keyName will be verify_doc_type, id_number, etc..
      foreach($row as $value){
      // do something
      echo $value;
     }
  }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This method will generate variables of same name as in POST array:

```
    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v )
    {
        $$k =  addslashes(trim($v ));
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit old, but I was recently trying to achieve this very same thing.

Hopefully the answer will point others in the right direction.

As per the documentation on [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

> Since PHP 7.1, keys can be specified

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
  $arr = ['locality' => 'Tunis', 'postal_code' => '1110'];

  list('postal_code' => $zipCode, 'locality' => $locality) = $arr;

  echo $zipCode; // will output 1110
  echo $locality; // will output Tunis
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php#121094